# Getting error "Register pair 1/2 contains wrong type" using custom loader

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to execute a program using my own customized loader and with the help of reflection. Few programs are working fine however with few I get this error..

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
  employeeTestTemp/CommissionedEmployee, method: setCommissionRate
  signature: (D)V) Register pair 1/2 contains wrong type at
  java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) at
  java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) at
  java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source) at
  java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)...
```

although the same program works perfectly fine when executed with default java loader.
Please Help...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I met this error message on a byte code program and the root cause is double takes two slot while my code visit the second half of it. 
My Oolong error code is:

```
.class Test
.method static run(DDDD) D
.limit locals 8
dload_0
dload_1
dmul
dload_2
dadd
dload_0
dmul
dload_3
dadd
dreturn
.end method
```

I guess it is caused by optimizer and suggest you recompile it with different configurations of jdk or use a different jdk.